# Do I need to set up Maven to be able to use Maven ant dependency task?

Tags: java, maven-2, ant

I was following these steps -
http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/dependencies.html

and got through. I have a silly question that do I need maven to be set up on my system to be able to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As per the [installation docs](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/installation.html):

> Maven Ant Tasks and all its dependencies are packaged together as a single JAR file.

The below works fine for me with the tasks jar in `$ANT_HOME/lib` and no `M2_HOME` set, no `mvn` executable on my path, and an empty `$CLASSPATH`:

```
<project name="test1" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
  <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/>

  <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
           uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
           classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath"/>

  <target name="get">
    <artifact:dependencies pathId="dependency.classpath">
      <dependency groupId="junit" artifactId="junit" version="3.8.2" scope="test"/>
    </artifact:dependencies>
  </target>
</project>
```

If I clear out `3.8.2` from my `~/.m2` repo directory, the artifact is downloaded properly.

Comment: ok, I am lil confused now. Thing is I already had maven set up on my system and I don't want to remove set up for sake of testing. One remotely located colleague of mine tried ant dependency thing and got this error - Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant:dependencies
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.......... So I was wondering if it coz he does not have maven set up.

Comment: @Tarun Where did they install the jar file? As long as it's installed in Ant's home `./lib` directory, the tasks should be available.

Comment: yup, it is. So I guess things are right at my end. Thanks for your response.